# How to assign a list of values to an element of a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to change the values of a dictionary according to some conditions.

```
mydic = {"10": [1, 2, 3], "20": [2, 3, 4, 7]}    
key = mydic.keys()    
val = mydic.values()    
aa = [None] * len(key)
for i in range(len(key)):
    for j in range(len(val[i])):    
        if val[i][j] <= 5:
            aa[i][j] = int(math.ceil(val[i][j]/10))
        else:
            aa[i][j] = "f"
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just interested in the values just loop over  mydic.itervalues():

```
import math

mydic = {"10": [1, 2, 3], "20": [2, 3, 4, 7]}

aa = [[] for _ in mydic]
for i, v in enumerate(mydic.itervalues()): # mydic.values() -> python 3
    for ele in v:
        if ele <= 5:
            aa[i].append(int(math.ceil(ele / 10.0))) # 10.0 for python2
        else:
            aa[i].append("f")
print(aa)
```

If you are using python 2 you will also need to use a float for division.

If you just want to update the dict forget about all the lists and just update directly:

```
for k,v in mydic.iteritems(): # .items() -> python 3
    for ind, ele in enumerate(v):
        if ele <= 5:
            mydic[k][ind] = (int(math.ceil(ele/10.)))
        else:
             mydic[k][ind] = "f"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
aa = [None] * len(key)
```

and this:

```
if val[i][j] <= 5:
    aa[i][j] = int(math.ceil(val[i][j]/10))
else:
    aa[i][j] = "f"
```

When you initialized `aa`, you set it to `[None, None]`.
So when you say `aa[i][j]`, you are saying `None[j]`, which of course is invalid.

I think what you are trying to do can be done like this:

```
aa = []
for index1, value in enumerate(mydic.values()):
    aa.append([])
    for index2, item in enumerate(value):
        if item <= 5:
            aa[index1].append(int(math.ceil(item/10)))
        else:
            aa[index1].append("f")
```